# Share all photos from Android phone with company Circle

Tags: google-workspace, google-plus

We use Google Apps and a bunch of Android phones. We do civil construction work and my people are always on the ground taking pictures with their Android phones. The phones are only for work-related use. It is perfect. People visit a lot of places to take pictures, Android puts GPS coordinates on them so it is easy to trace photos to locations and such.

All photos are automatically uploaded to Google+ but since the photos don't belong to an album at this point I cannot share them automatically with my back office team.

What I would like is: All photos taken are automatically uploaded and available for a Circle of users of the Google Apps domain, or to everyone in the Google Apps domain that has the link to the album. I don't want the user to have control over which photos are shared and which aren't.